Einsteins Coefficient of Absorption in solid state
What solid state parameter determines the probability of absorption (Einsteins coefficient B) in a material? Is it material dependent?
I think, I cannot say bandgap. Because if I have a source having energy beyond its bandgap the coefficient no longer depends on the bandgap, right? Please correct me if I am wrong.
